# What is a twisted D-module?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, connections, d-modules

Let $X/\mathbb{C}$ be an abelian variety, $Y$ be the dual abelian variety, and $P$ be the Poincaré bundle on $X\times Y$. On p.207, [Correction to “Sheaves with connection on abelian varieties”](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-87/issue-1/Correction-to-Sheaves-with-connection-on-abelian-varieties/10.1215/S0012-7094-97-08709-3.short) (by M. Rothstein), the remark says that $P$ is naturally a $D_{1,X\times Y/X}$-module, or the so-called twisted (relative) $D$-module (Remark on p.206).

But he does not define the sheaf $D_{1,X\times Y/X}$. I cannot find the definition online, neither. Does anyone have an idea about what it is? Your assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should look at Beilinson-Bernstein "proof of jantzen conjectures" for def of twisted differential operators.

Comment: Dear @GeordieWilliamson, thanks for your comment. For every line bundle $L$ on a smooth algebraic variety $V$, then $L$ is a canonical $D_L$-module (in the notation of "A proof of Jantzen conjectures"). I am not sure if it is what Rothstein has in mind.